# How to get notified when a realm object gets updated

Tags: android, database, realm

I have a table which stores the list of products. I want to get notified only when any of the row gets updated.Can I use RealmChangeListener. Below id my code

```
 public void updateProducts(final List<Product> products) {
    Realm realmObj = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    for (Product product : products) {
        if (product.shouldBeDeleted()) {
            delete(product.getBarcode());

        } else {
            realmObj.beginTransaction();
            realmObj.copyToRealmOrUpdate(product);
            realmObj.commitTransaction();
        }
    }
    realmObj.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use realm change listener...
I am using in my project like this

```
product.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmModel realmModel) {
                //Your code when any row update or insert new record
            }
        });
```

For detail you can refer this link

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmChangeListener.html

Comment: So, Will it be called even if a new entry is inserted in the table or only when the exiting row had been updated. Also I have to add this listener inside the loop.

Comment: @swati it will call when new entry made or existing row updated both the times

Comment: I want to get notified only when a updation has been done.

Comment: i don't think it is possible get notify if only any updation done...change listener will call every time...may be there are some ways but i don't know for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use our fine-grained collection notifications, which will report what kind of modification are done:

```
RealmResults<Product> products = realm.where(Product.class).findAll();
products.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Product>>() {
  @Override
  public void onChange(RealmResults<Product> products, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
    for (int i : changeSet.getChanges()) {
      // Item at index i was updated
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void updateProducts(final List<Product> products) {
    try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
            for (Product product : products) {
                if (product.shouldBeDeleted()) {
                    delete(product.getBarcode());
                } else {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(product);
                }
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

And elsewhere on UI thread:

```
private Realm realm;
private RealmResults<Product> results;
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Product>> listener = (element) -> {
    if(element.isLoaded()) {
        // results are loaded, or a change occurred!
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    results = realm.where(Product.class).findAllAsync();
    results.addChangeListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy(); 
    results.removeChangeListener(listener);
    results = null;
    realm.close();
}
```

**P.S.** you'll want to be notified on inserts and deletes as well, or your UI will get desynchronized. Thankfully that is the default behavior.

Comment: I want to get notified only when updation is done not the insertion. element.isLoaded() will return true in both the cases or it will return true for insertion and false for updation. Please help me as I am stuck with  this. Thanks!!

Comment: I am looking for the way which can tell me whether the record was inserted or updated. I don't want to traverse the table as there are thousand of records.

Comment: I do not know what you need this information for. There's a chance i'd just add a boolean field to my model that indicates whether this is a new object or an updated one.

Comment: I have to update other tables entries if one of the product gets update here. But there is no relation between these two.

Comment: ....why not do it in the same transaction? You know if it's just an update if the object already exists in the Realm.

Comment: yes, but to know that the object is present, I have to put a query which will traverse the thousand of product which is not efficient. Also, this query will run even if we have to insert the object which is also not sufficient. The number of rows is approx 20k.

Comment: ...if "efficiency" truly mattered you would not start a new transaction per every single element you're saving into the database. You can easily get whether an object already exists or not by querying the count of a query by primary key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153476/discussion-between-swati-and-epicpandaforce).